# CSS @import causes media queries class not work

Tags: html, css, import, media-queries

So i have run into something interesting. I like to have my css nice and neat and only want one reference of a style sheet in the <head> so to accomplish this i created a master css file that uses @import to bring in the rest of the style sheets. The problem I'm running into is that when you do this for some reason css media queries that use class selectors do not work but if you use ids it does... What gives?

**The HTML**

```
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
        <title>Some page</title>
        <link href=master.css rel=stylesheet>
    </head>
```

**The master.css**

```
@import url(css/some.css);
@import url(css/somemore.css);
@import url(css/media.css)
```

**The media.css**

```
/* This works */

@media all and (max-width: 380px) {
    #id1, #id2 {
        width: 88%;
    }
}


/* This doesn't */

@media all and (max-width: 380px) {
    .class1 {
        width: 88%;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your going to separate your css files i would use something like SASS or LESS. It will easily take care of this for you.

Comment: probably the width is overridden by another css style when you're using class selector. Try to specify more accurate path to the element (`.class1parent .class1`)

Comment: You're showing us the crayons but not the coloring book. Need to see the HTML.

Comment: @import in plain css is really bad practice. It for example destroys your loading times, as it needs to put in more requests.

Comment: Danny van Holten then what would you recommend? I would rather not have to use SASS or LESS as advised by @Bioto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why it was doing it my media queries were before my class in the style sheet...

```
/* This doesn't work */

@media all and (max-width: 380px) {
    .class1 {
        width: 88%;
    }
}

.class1 {
    width: 300px;
}
```

.

```
/* This works */

.class1 {
    width: 300px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 380px) {
    .class1 {
        width: 88%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last css rule is overriding previous one. The @media tag act like an `if`. So in your `/*doesnt work*/` one what it basically saying is

```
.class1 {/*This is your doesnt work code*/
    width: 88%;
}

.class1 {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Change the order of your universal code and media tags or use `!important` to solve this.

Comment: Already figured it out(see my answer) which is funny because i should have remembered this because i ran into it before.

Comment: It's okay i actually like your answer because you actual explain why that happens.